# Translate Scheme to CL

Tags: scheme, common-lisp, porting

I know Scheme a bit (read SICP long ago), wrote this program:

```
(define (prl k m)
  (define (print-line n)
    (cond ((> n 0) (display n)
                   (print-line (- n 1)))
          (else (newline))))
  (print-line k)
  (cond ((> m 1) (prl (+ k 1) (- m 1)))))
```

example - http://ideone.com/LuG45W

But i need this in CL, without using any macro. Can you help me with implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation from Scheme to CL in this case is pretty straightforward:

```
(defun prl (k m)
  (labels ((print-line (n)
             (cond ((> n 0)
                    (princ n)
                    (print-line (- n 1)))
                   (t (terpri)))))
    (print-line k)
    (cond ((> m 1)
           (prl (+ k 1) (- m 1))))))
```

For [example](http://ideone.com/aLZxXu):

```
(prl 3 4)
(terpri)
(prl 1 4)

321
4321
54321
654321

1
21
321
4321
```

Comment: This is wrong. DEFUN does not define local functions, as does DEFINE in Scheme.

Comment: @RainerJoswig what's you suggestion? taking the internal definition outside?

Comment: @Óscar López: a local function in Common Lisp is defined by `FLET` or `LABELS`. `LABELS` allows you to define self-recursive functions.

Comment: @RainerJoswig thanks, I wasn't aware of this `defun` behavior in CL. Fixed it.

Comment: @Óscar López: this is not special CL behavior. This is generally in Lisp so. In Emacs Lisp there isn't even FLET and LABELS. All you can usefully do is write top-level functions or use LET and LAMBDA. Alternatively there are macros from CL which provide FLET and LABELS in Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 4):

Scheme to Common Lisp.

- `SCHEME:DEFINE` on the top-level is `CL:DEFUN`.
- `SCHEME:DEFINE` as a local definition is `CL:FLET` or `CL:LABELS`.
- CL is by default and by standard not tail call optimizing. That means best use a) a TCO supporting implementation and direct the compiler to do so or b) use loops where necessary/possible. Note also that most interpreters will not do TCO in Common Lisp, even though the compiler might support it.

So the code will be:

```
(defun prl (k m)
  (flet ((print-line (n)
           (loop for i downfrom n downto 1 do (write i))
           (terpri)))
    (loop for i from k
          repeat m
          do (print-line i))))
```

Comment: Many languages do not tail call optimize and recursion is still though to be useful. Most CL implementation is partially or fully TCO-ed though: http://0branch.com/notes/tco-cl.html

Comment: @Sylwester: print many lines and we'll get a stack overflow without TCO. 'Many CL implementation are partially or fully TCO-ed' - if you use the compiler and the optimization values are set as such - plus you need to check the various restrictions. If you use an Interpreter or something like ABCL, which runs on the JVM, it won't work. Defensive programming says: avoid TCO.

Comment: Yep, You win. But really I did have to get more output than I wanted before I got a stack overflow (Clisp overflows after 7k calls or so) Shame on the pople who don't (compile 'prl) after testing that it works with small values :p

Answer (score 3):

As Rainer correctly points out, Óscar's solution is not quite correct, since `defun` defines a new function in the *global environment*. This should be a correct translation:

```
(defun prl (k m)
  (labels ((print-line (n)
             (cond ((> n 0)
                    (princ n)
                    (print-line (1- n)))
                   (t (terpri)))))
    (print-line k))
  (when (> m 1)
    (prl (1+ k) (1- m))))
```

But note that, unlike Scheme, the CL standard does not guarantee tail-call optimization. You'll have to check your implementation's documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

One does not *have* to have tail-recursion guarantee in a language with GOTO:

```
(defun prl (k m)                   ; (define (prl k m)
  (prog (n)
    PRL
      (setf n k)                   ;   (print-line k)
    PRINT-LINE                     ;   (define (print-line n)
      (cond ((> n 0) (princ n)     ;     (cond ((> n 0) (display n)
               (decf n)            ;              (print-line (- n 1)))
               (go PRINT-LINE))
            (t (terpri)))          ;           (else (newline))))
      (cond                        ;   (cond 
        ((> m 1)                   ;    ((> m 1) 
         (incf k)                  ;     (prl (+ k 1) (- m 1)))))
         (decf m) (go PRL)))))
```

Testing:

```
[19]> (prl 3 4)
321
4321
54321
654321
NIL
[20]> (prl 1 4)
1
21
321
4321
NIL
```

Comment: Other than resembling Fortran better, how is this version better than Joswig's?

Comment: @Sylwester *better*? Why should it be *better*? How about just being different? YMMV, but for some, the `loop` macro may be more arcane than `prog` with explicit goto's. As you know, a goto is nothing but a function call. or vice versa. :) Is `prog` not a part of CL spec? Is this code not in more direct correspondence with the original Scheme code?